# pysqlite and python : wont insert data into table but code executes fine

Tags: python, sqlite, pysqlite

I am trying to insert some data into a pysqlite database but even tho the code runs fine with no errors nothing shows up in the database and i have made sure that the variable does contain a value

```
    cur = self.con.execute("insert into urllist(url) values('%s')" % seed)
```

i have double checked the table and column name and they are also correct

Comment: Why do you mention `pysqlite`? That has been shipped as `sqlite3` with standard Python downloads since Python 2.5.

Comment: The pysqlite to which I refer IS pysqlite2. pysqlite1 (if it was ever called that) is ancient history. What version of Python are you running on what distro/version of what operating system? What do you import? `sqlite3`? `pysqlite2`? something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you calling con.commit() ?

Apparently changes are lost unless this method is used before closing the connection.

http://readthedocs.org/docs/pysqlite/en/latest/sqlite3.html

Comment: 99.9% chance Niall is correct. Data is not saved until you do a `COMMIT`. (More precisely: the new data will be visible to your python program, but won't be made visible to other programs until you do a `COMMIT`.)